# how to provide imagesource for an image in windows phone code behind(c#)

Tags: image, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone

This is not working while binding the image dynamically

```
Image Imgsource = new Image();

Imgsource.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Finder;component/Images/Chrysanthemum.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "binding dynamicaly" and what does "not working" mean? Not showing? giving an exception?

Comment: @anderZubi - Edited the Title.. Hope you understand now..

Comment: you need to bind through image converter

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates an `Image` element. But then you need to add that element to a container in the page. For example to the `LayoutRoot` Grid:

```
Image Imgsource = new Image();
Imgsource.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Finder;component/Images/Chrysanthemum.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(Imgsource);
```

Answer (score 1):

**you need to bind through image converter :**

```
 public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
 {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
           MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value,false);
           BitmapImage empImage = new BitmapImage();
           empImage.SetSource(memStream);
           return empImage; 
      }
      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```
  public void setimagebackgroud(string uri)
    {
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        imageBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 The binding as it should be done

 string s = "Hello";

 //Create the binding description   
 Binding b = new Binding("");   
 b.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;   
 b.Source = s;

 //Attach the binding to the target  
 MyText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);

 See if this helps
```